# why a tiny reordering of DOM Read/Write operations causes a huge performance difference

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox, dom

the following code illustrate the problem, changing the order of Read/Write causes a big difference in execution time (Tested using Chrome, Firefox and IE) :

```
// read->write->read->write...
function clearSlow(divs){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
        contents.push(div.clientWidth);
        div.style.width = "10px";
    });
}
// read->read->...->write->write...
function clearFast(divs){
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
        contents.push(div.clientWidth);
    });
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function(div) {
        div.style.width = "10px";
    });
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle for the complete example http://jsfiddle.net/Dq3KZ/2/ .

My results for n=100 :
Slow version : **~35ms**
Fast version : **~2ms**

for n=1000:
Slow version : **~2000ms**
Fast version : **~25ms**

I think this is related with the number of browser reflow in each case. In the slow scenario, a reflow happens for each write operation. However, in the fast scenario, the reflow occurs only once at the end. But I'm not sure and I don't understand why it does work that way (when the operations are independent).

**Edit:** I used `InnerText` property instead of `clientWidth` and `Style.Width` , I got the same behavior when using Google Chrome (http://jsfiddle.net/pindexis/CW2BF/7/). However, when `InnerHTML` is used, there's almost no difference (http://jsfiddle.net/pindexis/8E5Yj/).

**Edit2:** I have opened a discussion about the innerHTML/innerText issue for those interested: [why does replacing InnerHTML with innerText causes >15X drop in performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19256864/1117720)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The operations are not independent.

A reflow must occur when the style or content sizes changed **and** positions or dimensions are needed, either because you request a dimension or because the screen must be updated (when your code finishes).

`div.clientWidth` is a hidden function call. When you request this value, you request in fact an up to date value and thus, as the style changed, you trigger an immediate reflow.

In the "fast" case, there's no reason to do a reflow until the screen is redrawn or you request a size. Only one reflow is really needed in this case.

Comment: So it is the changing of the previous `div`'s width that triggers a reflow when the next `div`'s `clientWidth` is requested?

Comment: Changing the div width changes the reflow state (see http://www-archive.mozilla.org/newlayout/doc/reflow.html). But the reflow doesn't have to be done immediately, only when the result is needed. When you don't request the width, the reflow doesn't occur until the thread finishes (note that you can't really rely on this, I remember that Opera notes said that a reflow could occur sooner if the script execution was long). And what happens is made harder to predict due to the fact that reflows aren't always of the whole page.

Comment: Keep in mind that all this is implementation dependent but clearly changing and immediately reading in a loop is a kind of worst possible case.

Comment: but using InnerText instead of clientWidth produces the same results(in chrome, see my edit). I think no dimension is needed in this case.

Comment: Well, if you change the text, you might change the dimension of the "frame".

Comment: Case in point, changing the `color` style doesn't have the same speed problem.

Comment: almost no difference in speed using InnerHTML in contrast to InnerText (@edit)

Comment: As I said it's implementation dependent and hard to predict. Change for example divs with span and set contents of variable size in your fiddle and you'll see different results.

Comment: this is weird, in the innerHtml scenario, even if innerHTML changes frame dimension (tried `div.innerHTML="<p style='height:100px'>"`) it results low speed in both cases . However, reading InnerText instead of InnerHTML causes huge drop in performance in the slow case(I just replaced `contents.push(div.innerHTML)` with `contents.push(div.innerText)` )

Comment: `innerText` doesn't necessarily need to perform reflow, but it does need to perform style recalculation, since unlike `textContent` the returned value is style-dependent.