# why does replacing InnerHTML with innerText causes >15X drop in performance

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom

this question arises from my previous post [why a tiny reordering of DOM Read/Write operations causes a huge performance difference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19250971/1117720) .

consider the following code:

```
function clearHTML(divs) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
        contents.push(div.innerHTML);
        div.innerHTML = "";
    });
}

function clearText(divs) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(divs, function (div) {
        contents.push(div.innerText); //innerText in place of innerHTML
        div.innerHTML = "";
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pindexis/ZZrYK/

My test results for n=100:
ClearHTML: **~1ms**
ClearText: **~15ms**

for n=1000:
ClearHTML: **~4ms**
ClearText: **~1000ms**

I tested the code on google chrome and IE and get similar results (Firefox does not support innerText).

**Edit :**
the difference between the two functions is not caused by the slowness of innerText function compared to innerHTML, that's for sure ( I tried removing `div.innerHTML =""` and got boost in performance), there's strange browser reflow taking place here.

Comment: One has to interpret the html tags within and return you only the visible text.  The other just spits out the raw HTML.

Comment: Firefox's equivalent is `textContent`.

Comment: Try using the `textContent` property. it's faster than `innerText`

Comment: All those newfangled browsers support [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Comment: @JamesMontagne: The document's in-memory form is almost certainly closer to how the DOM represents it: as a tree of nodes, pre-processed, with text nodes as basically raw characters. (Inserting HTML whenever an element is inserted via the DOM doesn't make much sense, and could be painfully slow.) `innerHTML` traverses that tree the same as `innerText` does, but it also has to reconstruct the HTML tags etc. `innerText` can simply skip generating tags for those nodes, rather than generating them and trying to strip them out after the fact. Which should mean *less* work.

Comment: @cHao If I remember correctly though, `innerText` only returns visible text.  So `innerText` has to interpret things like css properties to determine which text actually matters.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: Again, though, the browser doesn't work directly with the source once the page is loaded.  It's not parsing CSS or HTML at runtime.  It does that at load time, and whenever someone sets an element's `innerHTML`, but doesn't bother otherwise.  A browser that tried to do all its work directly with the HTML or CSS source would be horribly slow.

Comment: @cHao Of course.  I suppose I was a bit brief in my comment.  My use of "interpret" was not meant to imply "parse" and "html tags" was meant more as "elements".

Comment: @JamesMontagne: `innerHTML` has to traverse the tree and interpret stuff too, though (lest non-elements and modified elements be represented by the wrong HTML).  The big question in my mind is whether/how/why an "am i visible?" check (which can eliminate entire subtrees, cutting the work even more) really costs 250x more time than unparsing HTML.

Comment: [jsben.ch](http://jsben.ch)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As [MDN explains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent#Differences_from_innerText):

> As innerText is aware of CSS styling, it will trigger a reflow, whereas textContent will not.

Using `textContent` instead of `innerText` does not cause reflow and is also fast.  IE9+ also supports it as does FFX/Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

The difference almost certainly comes from the extra effort it takes to get the InnerText (which I believe removes extraneous tags and just returns the text within an element). InnerHTML on the other hand simply returns data that has already been parsed and understood by the browser.