# Is there any way to optimize my client side search function?

Tags: javascript, optimization, search

I've created a page that needs to show all records from a table, instead of paginating.
The problem is that my search function actually takes about 10 seconds to run for 1300 records. Is there any way to optimize it?

I'm using bootstrap `d-none` class to hide elements.

```
if (document.getElementById("form_search_user")) {
    document.getElementById("form_search_user").addEventListener("submit",function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        let start = performance.now();

        let search = document.getElementById("search_input").value;
        let table_row = document.querySelectorAll(".user_table tbody tr");

        table_row.forEach(element => {
            element.innerText.toUpperCase().indexOf(search.toUpperCase()) > -1 ? 
            element.classList.remove("d-none") : element.classList.add("d-none");
        });
        console.log(((performance.now() - start) / 1000).toFixed(3));
    })
}
```

Comment: Instead of a `forEach` loop, you should simply use a `for()` loop. Those perform better than other loops in JS. Just a tip. Another tip would be to make the search element value uppercase before the loop and not inside it. Right now you perform that function on each loop while you only need to do that once. Just a very minor improvement, but an improvement none the less.

Comment: There are numerous 3rd-party table controls ([example](https://datatables.net/)) that have inbuilt pagination and search/filter capabilities. The good ones will perform much better than 10 seconds for a simple filter.

Comment: @icecub you're right about the `toUpperCase()` before the loop, but the `for()` loop was almost a second slower than `forEach()`.

Comment: I honestly think something else is going on with your script though. I made a test script with your problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/b3gekc29/ Also showing the same and my solution. Both performing at such speeds that a human eye won't notice it.

Comment: Are you sure you're only filtering client side? Or are you actually performing some SQL queries in the background and filtering the results live? Because if the latter, then JS isn't your issue. The issue is most likely your SQL query. Perhaps the table is not normalized, there are no good indexes on the table or there's simply too much data to go through? In any case, if SQL is the issue and you can't improve it, you might want to consider better solutions. Like maybe a websocket and load the database data into the server's RAM? But that would be my kind of solution to that issue.

Comment: My problem really was with the styling, as @Bergi mentioned below. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `.innerText` which is [known to be slow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19256864/1048572) because it has to take styling into account. You probably want to search in `.textContent` instead.

Comment: Didn't know about that. Tremendous performance gain, from average 12-13secs to less than a hundredth. Thank you.